# Extending background vertically in responsive sizes

Tags: html, css, background

I have a background working fine with 1024X768px but when the responsive position turns to 768X1024, my background did not extend up to the footer. In other sizes like 480x320 and vice versa my background repeats vertically. I want my background to extend when responsive position turns to 768X1024 and also in 480c320. Can you tell me the best solution for this?

I tried to use this but it's not working.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){

    .container .mybg {background-size:100%;}


}
```

*note: need to cut some contents.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
     <div class="container">    
        <!--Background-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

            <div class="mybg">

                <div class="container"> 
                    <div class="row-fluid text-center">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="img-thumbnail">
                          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/winning 
                              logo.png" alt="...">
                                <div class="container">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h5><a href="Portlogo.html">Logo Design</a></h5>        
                                  </div>

                                </div>


                        </div>  
                       </div>
                    </div>                                        
                </div>

            </div><!--END OF MYBG-->

        </div><!--END OF Background-->


    </div>

    <!--bacground pattern 2 underneath-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/BG-w-pattern_line_2.png">
    </div><!--END OF bacground pattern 2 underneath-->  

        <div class="container">
                <div class="footer">
                     <div class="container">
                          <p class="mytext-muted">Copyright &copy;  2014. All rights 
                              reserved. EGT Design.</p>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){

.container .mybg {background-size:100%;}
}

.container .mybg{

background:url(../images/ContentBG.png);}
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you provide JSfiddle link

Comment: you can use background-size:cover; insted of background-size:100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
.container .mybg {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;      
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: this code worked in some sizes but when it reaches to 768x1024 it didn't work, can you help?

Comment: Sure, could you provide a link to the problem?